# How to parse dates and times with 00 minutes and 00 seconds in r?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I have a large dataset with dates and times as a 16-digit (in the form `yyyymmddhhmmssss` or `2005031600003000`) character string.

I have written the following parsing command (dropping the last 2 digits from the string):

```
DATA[, 1 ] <- substr(DATA[, 1 ], 1, 14)
DATA[, 1 ] <- ymd_hms(DATA[, 1 ], quiet = FALSE)
```

The parsing works fine except for times with 00 minutes and 00 seconds (for example `2005030507000000`) which fail to parse.

Is there a fix to this problem? `parse_date_time` command has exactly the same problem.

Comment: Ismo, if my answer solved your problem consider to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: The problem was that even 00 minutes and 00 second times were read in as scientific notations. Using {options(scipen=999)} fixed the issue. The last two digits of the seconds were dropped as they were all zeros. Did not try formatting with 4 digit seconds, would have probably worked as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try `as.POSIXct` and pass the last two zeros to format

```
x <- c("2005031600003000", "2005030507000000")
as.POSIXct(x, format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S00")
# [1] "2005-03-16 00:00:30 CET" "2005-03-05 07:00:00 CET"
```

From `?strptime`

> %H : Hours as decimal number (00–23) ...
>
> %M : Minute as decimal number (00–59)
>
> %S : Second as integer (00–61) ...